Troubleshooting Issues with Previously Functional Mobile Screen Scrolling Code: Could Recent Android or Appium Updates Be the Cause?
I am encountering an issue with scrolling on a mobile screen. Although the scrolling code worked previously, it now fails with the error: "NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters." The error occurs specifically at the method AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls.
Here is my fuction:
def Documents_Uploads_Screen(self):
    def click_element(xpath):
        el = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        el.click()

    click_element('//*[@text="Documents"]')

    # Driving License
    click_element(
        '//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id="insure.agencify.agencify:id/btn_camera"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="Shutter"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Done"]')

    # Logbook
    click_element(
        '//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[2]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id="insure.agencify.agencify:id/btn_camera"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="Shutter"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Done"]')

    # National ID
    click_element(
        '//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[3]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id="insure.agencify.agencify:id/btn_camera"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="Shutter"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Done"]')

    self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR,
                             'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).setAsVerticalList().scrollToEnd(5)')

    # Backside of National ID
    click_element(
        '//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[4]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id="insure.agencify.agencify:id/btn_camera"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="Shutter"]')
    click_element('//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Done"]')

    el = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@text="Continue"]')))
    el.click()

I want it to scroll upwards after uploading National ID so that I can upload the backside of the the National ID
